# Why Native DOM event always reset React Component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I know that the **Synthetic Event**, instead of the **native dom event**, should be the way to deal with interaction in React App, but I wonder why the behavior is so bizarre. When the React Event works well, and the dom event always reset the state to initial state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  function clickMe() {
    setNum(num + 1);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("app_btn").addEventListener("click", clickMe);
    return () =>
      document.getElementById("app_btn").removeEventListener("click", clickMe);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <div>App {num}</div>
      <button id="app_btn">DOM click</button> <br />
      <button onClick={clickMe}>React Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The full project can be opened here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wqrmcu?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because your native event handler still closes over the value of `num` that was available after first render (that value is 0). You need to add and remove native event listener at each state update for this to work like so :-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("app_btn").addEventListener("click", clickMe);
    return () =>
      document.getElementById("app_btn").removeEventListener("click", clickMe);
  }, [num]);
```

Another approach could be using a callback inside the state updator function as @Mahdi pointed out. This will allow you to get new state on the basis of previous state. But still the value of `num` being accessible to native event listener is 0. You can verify that by doing a `console.log(num)` inside `clickMe`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function clickMe() {
    setNum(prevNum => prevNum + 1); // <-- you need this
  }
```

Comment: Thansk, I actually find the solution, but does not know why my version works with react event, but not the dom native event